# Определение перегруженного оператора вне класса(структуры)

Tags: c++

```
struct String
{
    String(size_t n, char c);
    ~String();
    String &operator=(const String &other);///////////////////////

    size_t size;
    char *str;
};
```

Пишу `String::String &operator=(const String &other);` - подчеркивается компилятором. Как правильно?

Comment: так а что за ошибку-то пишет? [справка](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так это делается:

```
String & String::operator = (const String & other)
{
    // ...
}
```